# how to pass map values to adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-gridview, android-adapter

I have this adapter

```
public class BookcaseAdapter extends SectionableAdapter implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Activity activity;
    private Map<String, List<Sponsor>> mSponsorMap;

    public BookcaseAdapter(Activity activity, LayoutInflater inflater,
            int rowLayoutID, int headerID, int itemHolderID, int resizeMode, Map<String, List<Sponsor>> sponsorMap) {
        super(inflater, rowLayoutID, headerID, itemHolderID, resizeMode);
        this.activity = activity;
        mSponsorMap = sponsorMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSponsorMap.size(); ++i) {
            if (position < mSponsorMap.get(i).size()) {
                return mSponsorMap.get(i).get(position);
            }
            position -= mSponsorMap.get(i).size();
        }
        // This will never happen.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getDataCount() {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mSponsorMap.size(); ++i) {
            total += mSponsorMap.get(i).size();
        }
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSectionsCount() {
        return mSponsorMap.size();
    }


    @Override
    protected int getCountInSection(int index) {
        return mSponsorMap.get(index).size();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getTypeFor(int position) {
        int runningTotal = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < mSponsorMap.size(); ++i) {
            int sectionCount = mSponsorMap.get(i).size();
            if (position < runningTotal + sectionCount)
                return i;
            runningTotal += sectionCount;
        }
        // This will never happen.
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getHeaderForSection(int section) {
        List<List<Sponsor>> l = new ArrayList<List<Sponsor>>(mSponsorMap.values());
        String string = l.get(section).get(0).getCountry_name();
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindView(View convertView, int position) {
        String title = (String) getItem(position);
        ImageView label = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.bookItem_title);
        label.setImageResource(R.drawable.place_holder_thumb);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
        ImageView label = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.bookItem_title);
//      String text = label.getText().toString();
//      i.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, text);

//      activity.startActivity(i);
        label.setImageResource(R.drawable.place_holder_thumb);
    }

}
```

When from my activity I call this adapter and pass to sponsorMap values it's getting null and I have null pointer exceptoin.

I debug it found that when I call adapter and it's reach to `super(inflater, rowLayoutID, headerID, itemHolderID, resizeMode);` and after that called

```
@Override
    protected int getSectionsCount() {
        return mSponsorMap.size();
    }
```

I'am sure that mSponsorMap=sponsormap not called ever. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be called but later, the exception you got when the the super constructor is invoked prevent your constructor code from being actually reached.

Just add an NPE guard in your overriden method:

```
@Override
protected int getSectionsCount() {
   return mSponsorMap == null ? 0 : mSponsorMap.size();
}
```

Alternatively you could also initialize your mSponsorMap to an empty Map:

```
private Map<String, List<Sponsor>> mSponsorMap = Collections.emptyMap();
```

And then in your constructor do:

```
mSponsorMap.putAll(sponsorMap);
```

Cheers,

Comment: i tried above two codes but it still crash plz help